# R loop matrix comparing whether the first column is the same as the other column

Tags: r, if-statement

I wanted would like to check whether in each column of a matrix the values are the same as in the first column:

```
 x1  <- c("x", "y", "x")
 x2  <- c("x", "y", "y")
 x3  <- c("y", "y","x")

 dat <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3)

   x1 x2 x3
1  x  x  y
2  y  y  y
3  x  y  x
```

So if x2 != 2, there should be a "1", otherwise a NA. How can I do that? The result in this case would be:

```
x2     x3 
NA     1
NA     NA
1      NA
```

My (not working) solution was:

```
fun <- function (x) {
for(j in 2: ncol(x)){
  ifelse(x[,1]== j, NA,1)
}
}
```

fun(dat)

I would need a function to perform this with lapply. How can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier with the wrapper `sapply` as it applies applies the names to the result:

```
sapply(dat[-1], 
       function(x) 
          ifelse(as.character(x)==as.character(dat[[1]]), NA, 1)
)
##      x2 x3
## [1,] NA  1
## [2,] NA NA
## [3,]  1 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Different approach using the fact that column-operations are often easy because of argument recycling:

```
 dat <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # keeps as character 

 ne.dat1 <-  (dat != dat[,1])[ , -1]  # True/False rather than 1,NA
 is.na(ne.dat1) <- !ne.dat1
 ne.dat1
       x2   x3
[1,]   NA TRUE
[2,]   NA   NA
[3,] TRUE   NA
```

Comment: Likely scales better than any `*apply` method.  I particularly like the `is.na<-` here.

Comment: I forgot to put in the stringsAsFactor=FALSE step.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
 m1 <- (!(as.character(dat[,1])==dat[,-1])) +1
 m1[] <- c(NA,1)[m1]
 m1
 #    x2 x3
 #[1,] NA  1
 #[2,] NA NA
 #[3,]  1 NA
```

Comment: Excellent. Sidesteps the conversion process elegantly. If the dataframe is all column factors, do you need `as.character` around both instances of `dat[,]` in the first step?

Comment: @BondedDust, Thanks. When I tried `dat[,1]==dat[,-1]`, it gave error: ` Error in dat[, 1] == dat[, -1] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented`

Comment: Right. They were factors in the dataframe created by tobias. That's why I re-did the creation of 'dat', and that's why I thought you would need to use `as.character` on both sides.